# Appcelerator Studio Debugger ignores breakpoints

Tags: appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-studio

**Summary**: debugger ignores breakpoints on Appceleration Titanium Studio IDE.

I'm using Appcelerator Studio, build: 4.10.0.201709271713, fresh install on macOS 10.14.1 (Mojave). My iOS project compiles and runs on the simulator just fine, everything behaves properly normally.

When I try and debug, however, execution ignores any breakpoints and just barrels on. I've checked all obvious settings, tried setting breakpoints every way possible, no luck.

If I launch the app under debug in the simulator and just let it sit there, eventually a dialog box will pop up saying "'iOS debugger on simulator...' has encountered a problem. Debugger failed to connect".

Anyone out there know what to do from here? I've been using Studio for years and the debugger part has always 'just worked'. I'm not sure where to look for port and connection settings.

Comment: It was a known [bug](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TISTUD-9110) in Appcelerator Studio build 5.1.0...

Comment: Thanks for that link, this certainly describes the problem I'm encountering.  I confess to being confused in that Studio claims to be build 4.10.0 and I have no pending update notices.